# How to concatenate three 2D arrays and then display result as an image?

Tags: java, arrays, 3d, 2d, concatenation

I have three 2D arrays each holding red, green and blue pixel values of an image respectively.  The initial image used is a blurred image which is then split up into these RGB values so that I can run a function over each array to deblur the images.  I then need to concatenate these arrays (possibly to make a new 3D array) and display the resulting image.

So far I've tried to use System.arraycopy() but this only gives me int values and I'm working with arrays of doubles.

I've also tried to stack each 2D array onto each other to create the 3D array like so,

```
    for(int i = 0; i<redPixels.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<redPixels[0].length; j++){
            concatPixels[i][j][1] = redPixels[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<greenPixels.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<greenPixels[0].length; j++){
            concatPixels[i][j][2] = greenPixels[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<bluePixels.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<bluePixels[0].length; j++){
            concatPixels[i][j][3] = bluePixels[i][j];
        }
    }
```

but I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when it comes to the third for loop when I'm try to add the bluePixels to the concatPixels array.

Also once I'm able to concatenate the 2D arrays how can I then display a 3D array as an image.  I've been working with BufferedImage's which only seem to deal with 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Images are usually stored in RGB[A] (PNG format) formats or BGR or maybe other arrangements (which may include an alpha channel as well). So if you want a PNG format, your code will look something like this :

```
int[][][] array = new int[redPixels.length][redPixels[0].length][3] ;
for(int i = 0; i<redPixels.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<redPixels[0].length; j++){
        concatPixels[i][j][0] = redPixels[i][j];
        concatPixels[i][j][1] = greenPixels[i][j];
        concatPixels[i][j][2] = bluePixels[i][j];
    }
}
```

The code assumes that the redPixels, greenPixels and bluePixels are exactly identical in number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  For some reason I still get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when it comes to the line concatPixels[i][j][3] = bluePixels[i][j]; even though all the lengths of my arrays are 1024.

Comment: Ah yes of course! Brilliant thanks! Sorry I can't vote up as I don't have enough rep. Would you know how to then display the 3D array as an image?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html